# Advantage Database Server: Change User Password/Add User

Tags: advantage-database-server

I was introduced recently to the Advantage Database technology, and I now have to use it to interface with a legacy software on Win 7. I have successfully followed the advantagezone development help files in order to install both the ADS and the ODBC driver. A few questions remain, the first of which being the following: How does one change the password of a user/add a user?

I was unable to find any documentation regarding this matter. Could you point me to the relevant documentation or provide me with the command necessary to do so via command line?

Also I was wondering if there were any sort of GUI to manage the ADS, like MySQL has with PHPMyAdmin or the MySQL workbench.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: The GUI utility is the Advantage Data Architect, available from the [ADS website](http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com) - look in the *Product Downloads* section. It comes with a help file that has information about using the Advantage Data Dictionary, which includes adding users and roles.

Comment: Thanks Ken - you successfully answered my question. Cheers!

Comment: @KenWhite: I successfully installed ARC, but there is no documentation in either the installation directory, and the [official documentation](http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/webhelp/Advantage11.1/index.html) about how to use ARC and set up a new connection/create new users is about nonexistent. Would you have any extra documentation I could refer to?
Just as a heads-up, due to some changes in plans, I had to move to linux, and now I am running the latest ARC under wine.

Comment: The documentation should be installed already. What happens when you click the large **?** in the ARC toolbar? You can also see the [Advantage Online Help Files](http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/content.aspx?key=32).

Comment: I must admit I didn't see that there was a link to the Advantage Online Help Files in the ARC. However this doesn't provide any more information - as I said the official documentation is rather ambiguous/incomplete regarding that matter. Isn't there anything else I can refer to?

Comment: The documentation contains an entire book (*The Advantage Developer's Guide*) which was commercially published and sold. I'm not sure how that's *rather ambiguous/incomplete*; it's a **book** that includes narrative, tutorials, and code samples. *Part 1, Chapter 4* has an entire section on *Adding Users*.

Comment: Oh man, you are right - _The Advantage's Developer Guide_ seems definitely much more complete. I completely overlooked it because there was a section at the root level of the documentation specifically for the ARC. It's somewhat counter-intuitive to have half your documentation outlined in top-level folders and then have the totality in one of the subfolders. This being said, onwards to some good reading.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: I confirm, _The Advantage's Developer Guide_ saved my day!

Comment: FInally had time to write a proper answer for you. It contains all of the information I previously provided in my comments, as well as a couple of other tips and a link to the printed Developers Guide at Amazon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Advantage Database Server (ADS) uses a somewhat strange concept they've confusingly called a *Data Dictionary* (DD), which when used as designed controls users, rights, security, and access similar to what most DBMSs offer in the database itself.

Basically the only way to work with the ADS DD is through their GUI, known as the Advantage Data Architect (ARC32), which is available for download from the [ADS Developer Zone](http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com). (You can do it via code, but for the types of things a DBA would do it's much easier to do things via ARC32.) Using it, you can create most of the types of things you'd typically use in a DBMS.

ARC32 also allows you to design your tables and indexes, as well as running SQL DDL and DML statements. The supported SQL grammar is also available in the documentation and covered in the book mentioned below.

You can find the documentation in ARC32 itself (using the Help menu or the *?* on the toolbar), or via their [Online Help FIles](http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/content.aspx?key=32). The best place to start is in the topic *The Advantage Developer's Guide*, which is actually the entire contents of the book [Advantage Database Server: A Developer's Guide](http://smile.amazon.com/Advantage-Database-Server-Developers-Guide/dp/1453769978/ref=sr_1_2?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1461362000&sr=1-2&keywords=Advantage+Developers+Guide). The book contains pretty good documentation on all of the aspects of both ARC32 and ADS itself, including use of the DD. Part 1, Chapter 4 has an entire section on adding users.